# Passing an array of double value from one java class to another

Tags: java

I have an Java class file that contains an array of double values that I wanted to use in another Java class file. This is the simplified version of my code:

File1.java

```
public class File1.java{

//code

public void compute
{
    double[] vectorX_U = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5}
}

//i tried this method to pass but it said vectorX_U cannot be resolved to a variable
 public Double[] getvectorX_U() 
 {
     return vectorX_U;
 }
```

File2.java

```
//i attempt to use the array
public void computethis
{
    File1 td = new File1();
    System.out.println(td.getvectorX_U());
}
```

Can I have some help on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: you need to define `vectorX_U ` at class level and not localy in the `compute` method

Comment: should be a property, not inside your method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your File1 is riddled with errors.

Basically (besides the compilation errors), you need to have your array of doubles as an instance variable.

As it is now, it is a local variable within the compute method, and your get method has no access to it.

File1.java

```
public class File1{ // no .java here!

double[] vectorX_U;

public void compute
{
    vectorX_U = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5}
}


 public Double[] getvectorX_U() 
 {
     return vectorX_U; // now it will find the instance variable
 }
}
```

EDIT:

you will need to call the compute method before calling the getvectorX_U, though.
If you don't, the array will not be initialized, and the getter will return null.

Comment: Thanks but when I tried to output it in File2 using "td.compute().getvectorX_U();" a syntax error "Cannot invoke getvectorX_U() on the primitive type void" occur. Know why?

Comment: use compute method in your constructor first and then call td.getVectorX_U();

Comment: @Cael not td.compute().getvectorX_U();, but td.compute(); td.getvectorX_U(); you can't chain those, because compute doesn't return anything, and you are trying to run the getter on the (non-existing) result of compute.

Answer (score 0):

if you don`t want change the arrays value and all the class can use it as "global variable" you can set

```
public class File1.java{

   public static final double[] VECTORX_U = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5};

   ............

}
```

if you want change it and every this variable in instances are same

```
public class File1.java{

   static double[] vectorX_U = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5};

   ............

}
```

if variable in every instance of this class has a special value

```
public class File1.java{

   double[] vectorX_U = {0.1, 0.2, 0.5};

   ............

}
```

for the first and second  you can use File1.variable ,the third you need create a instance of this class then  you can use it

Answer (score -1):

Basically your vectorX_U variable's scope is inside the compute method. So non of other methods can access the vectorX_U variable. so it should be a global variable.

Comment: there are no global variables in Java, you may want to change that to 'instance variable' instead.

Comment: @Stultuske well my idea is to show the variable to all the methods. instance variable does not make that sense as we can create instance variables inside the method as initially done here. But global means that it is instance variable but its defined outside the methods.

Comment: "as we can create instance variables inside the method" ... no, we can not. If we create it within a method, it is not an instance variable, it is a local variable. What you are describing, is an instance variable.